# If the parameter is null, select all records. Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a query, in which some parameters can sometimes arrive null, and when these arrive null, I want them to ignore those conditions.

```
SELECT DISTINCT on (i.empleado) i.id
FROM rrhh.imputacion as i 
  INNER JOIN rrhh.empleado as e ON e.id = i.empleado 
  JOIN commons.persona AS pe ON e.persona_comun = pe.id 
  INNER JOIN rrhh.parte__imputaciones as pi ON pi.imputacion = i.id 
  INNER JOIN rrhh.parte as p ON pi.parte = p.id 
  WHERE i.dia >= '2017-12-04' AND i.dia <= '2017-12-11' and p.borrador = false  AND e.fecha_fin_contrato IS NULL AND e.security_domain_id = 2 
  and i.empleado = 126
ORDER  BY i.empleado, i.dia DESC,i.id
```

I need if the value of my parameter:

"and i.empleado = 126" <- if the value is NULL, ignore this, and bring all the records, without filtering by i.empleado

I do not see concrete examples for postgres.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you pass this value? Java/C#/Php?

Comment: java: setParameter("empleado", specifitacion.getEmpleado())  (LONG)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways of achieving this

1. Check the parameter in application code and add the condition only when value is non-null.
2. Add an `OR` condition on the value to test its nullability. Something like so:

   ```
   and (? is null or i.empleado = ?)
   ```

   In Java, you'd have to apply the parameter twice in this case.
   But if you are using Spring's `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`, you can get away with setting it only once:

   ```
   and (:emp is null or i.empleado = :emp)
   ```